# Can highcharts format X axis label differently?

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to achieve this kind of behaviour (as showed in the attached image), is it possible? Basically the x axis label is formatted differently:

1. If it is the first label, format Month Year 

2. If it is still the same year, only format month.

3. If the label is in a different year now, format Month Year again.

[image]

My feeling is that it can't. Then can I pass down a list of formatted date as Axis label?

Many Thanks

Comment: USe [`xAxis.labels.formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter).

Comment: worked this out myself.

Comment: see the fiddle if anyone is interested. http://jsfiddle.net/xuaLazgn/